# Connect to Firebase buckets

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-storage

I have a backend in golang and was wondering how I can connect to Firebase storage to create/delete buckets and add/delete files. Can I use the Admin sdk. I found the client storage lib in golang for google cloud storage. Can I use that?  And whats the difference between firebase storage and google cloud storage?

Answer (score 1):

The app I'm working on connects to Firebase Storage Buckets via the Admin SDK, but we're using Firebase Functions in Node.js.  However, it looks like the Admin SDK in Go offers the same Storage access, and it's documented (with example code in Go) here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

I like using Admin in Firebase, because you don't have to worry about project configuration and authentication to the various services.  Firebase storage is google cloud storage, but with a nice wrapper and well-integrated into other aspects of your Firebase project.  You get some limitations as a trade-off for all of that convenience, but unless you run into a feature of Google Cloud that you absolutely need and doesn't exist in Firebase, I'd stick with the Firebase (and Admin) version.